# Android Studio can't add elements to the layout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to create my first app in Android Studio with Kotlin. The installation worked fine. However if I drag any element onto the Layout, it's not showing up properly. The only change I can see, is a little white dot, that appears as soon as the Layout contains any element. I can select it and view the element attributes on the right, but nothing more.
If I run the app, all elements are squashed in the top left corner.
I already reinstalled Android Studio.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone know how to fix my problem?
Thaks in advance!

Here is some more information:

[XML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KE26.png), 
[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWN2b.png)

Comment: Try to add attributes to one of your views in the xml file, like:         
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent". Is there any difference?

Comment: Still the same! Its not showing anything.

Comment: Can you show us your XML code for the layout, as well as what the (!) messages are in your screenshot? More information is helpful.

Comment: Hey, I gave you some more information. Any idea how to fix it? (I made a new Answer. I dont know how to post images in a Comment...)

Answer (score 1):

Make the constraint layout width and height as match_parent in text editor. and then try adding widgets in the design view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some more information:

[XML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KE26.png), 
[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWN2b.png)

Comment: Just a hint: It's better to edit the question and post the code there.